# Какая логика работы командной строки при исполнении команды python -i <имя файла>.py

Tags: python, cmd

Столкнулся с проблемой - при запуске файла с разрешением `.py` (python) в командной строке, программа мгновенно исполняется и прекращает работу. При этом невозможно увидеть вывод программы.

Это вывод программы. Точнее его отсутствие.

[image: Исполнение программы командной строкой]

В программе используется модуль `tkinter`. Поэтому при исполнении программы должно открываться окно с холстом и рисунками.

При изучении вопроса нашел такой вариант решения проблемы:

> ...путь к файлу>`python -i` 12_colorrect.py

Этот вариант работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:

Синтаксис `-i` может выдавать различный результат в зависимости от контекста. Это можно посмотреть здесь:  [Самый полный справочник по параметрам командной строки](http://4its.ru/html/windows-cmd.html).

Но какова логика работы командной строки при использовании `-i` в контексте `python -i 12_colorrect.py`?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В документации питона всё написано: `-i` [запускает интерактивную консоль после отрабатывания скрипта](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i). И так как консоль открыта, переменные скрипта продолжают висеть в памяти и окно тоже продолжает висеть, что логично

Comment: Спасибо. Значит я не там искал.

Comment: вы бы показали модуль `12_colorrect.py`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду код из файла `12_colorrect.py`?

Comment: там нехватает главного цикла tk - это и так понятно..)